# PayPal IPN 503 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

For the last 8 days I've not been getting any order information from PayPal when a customer purchases something.

I've checked my IPN settings in my PayPal account and in the history log it shows:

HTTP response code 503

Delivery status Failed

My notification URL is `https://example.com/paypal/ipn/`

I've also tried it without https and with the www

I'm using PayPal Website Payments Standard. There's no errors in my logs and no paypal log (as the request obviously isn't reaching Magento.

I've whitelisted the PayPal domain on the server firewall.

I've upgraded Magento from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4 but that hasn't helped either.

When I check the URL with a server header checker I get a 200 response.

PHP Version 5.3.23

How else can I debug what's going on?

Comment: you have to start from php and system packages upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to recent PayPal SSL certificate upgrade.

> PayPal is in the process of upgrading the SSL certificates used to secure our web sites and API endpoints. These new certificates will be signed using the SHA-256 algorithm and VeriSign’s 2048-bit G5 Root Certificate. You will need to ensure that your environment supports the use of the SHA-256 signing algorithm and discontinue the use of SSL connections that rely on the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate. This action must be taken by June 17, 2016 in order to avoid any disruption of service.

Additional information in links below:

[Security-Related Changes Required to Avoid Service Disruption](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#ssl)

[SSL Certificate Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: I think this is probably the answer as the SSL cert is SHA-256 and G2 Root however the PayPal site states http only IPN messages will be supported until June 2017. I've switched my postback url to use http instead of https and I'm still getting 503 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a crashed database table. Once that was fixed everything started working normally.

Comment: Which database table was affected please?