# PayPal IPN postback HTTP error: SSL warning

Tags: ipn

We are receiving this error message when debugging the IPN from PayPal:

> PayPal IPN postback HTTP error: error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

We have noticed that it may be related to not being updated to the last PayPal changes, as stated [here in the answer and comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124999/paypal-ipn-503-error/125005#125005).

Did anyone using an http:// website encounter the same issues? Should we simply go through https:// and the error would be fixed that way?

Thanks for any orientation.

Comment: try contact paypal now only.....

Comment: Clients did, and PayPal said is our system. I will contact PayPal myself. By the looks of it, PayPal Standard (which is being left aside in favor of Express Checkout) would need to go through httpS to update the Order status and make the transactional mails to be sent - but I'm still not sure, any help is appreciated!

Comment: when i contacted paypal through email, they replied after 1 week....